# this.setState is not pushing items into an array when using a for loop in React

Tags: reactjs

How can I transfer individual items from one array into another using react?

I have an array of items in state I created, but I need to send them one by one into another state. What's the best way to do this? I tried callback functions and I'd rather not use `setTimeone`.

```
state = { imageChosen: [] };    

// Choose multiple images to upload
fileSelectedHandler = event => {
    let tmp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
      tmp.push(event.target.files[i])
    }
    this.setState({ imageChosen: tmp }, () => this.uploadMedia());
  }
  // Add chosen images to the media chosen array
  uploadMedia = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.imageChosen.length; i++) {
      this.setState({ 
        mediaChosenArr: [...this.state.mediaChosenArr, this.state.imageChosen[i]],
        displayMediaChosenArr: [...this.state.displayMediaChosenArr, URL.createObjectURL(this.state.imageChosen[i])],
        imageChosen: [],
      });
    }
    document.getElementById("mediaPlaceholder").value = '';
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `setState()` with `for-loop` is not recomendable.

**EDITED**

```
fileSelectedHandler = event => {
  let mediaChosenArr = [];
  let displayMediaChosenArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
    mediaChosenArr.push(event.target.files[i]);
    displayMediaChosenArr.push(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
    });
  }
  this.setState({
    mediaChosenArr: mediaChosenArr,
    displayMediaChosenArr: displayMediaChosenArr
  });
  document.getElementById("mediaPlaceholder").value = ''; // It seems not good.
}
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the update I just made and let me know if there's a way to do this?

Comment: What can I do if the mediaChosenArr and displayMediaChosenArr states already have content in their array that I need to append to?

Comment: NVM, I got it. I just needed to push the existing state into those initial variables. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid calling `setState` from inside a loop as each call to `setState` will result in a render.

Instead assemble the `imageChosen` array first, and then pass it to `setState`. Also since you're not modifying the files array you should just be able to pass it directly to `setState` without looping through it.

Also keep in mind [state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

```
fileSelectedHandler = event => {
  const files = event.target.files;
  this.setState(
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using template array.

```
state = { imageChosen: [] };    

fileSelectedHandler = event => {
   let tmpArray = [...imageChosen];
   for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {

     tmpArray.push(event.target.files[i]);

     console.log(event.target.files[i])
   }

   this.setState({imageChosen: tmpArray})

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several ways, here is one with forEach.

```
const initialArray = ['one.png','two.png','three.png']
this.state = { imageChosen: [] }; 
let {imageChosen} = this.state
initialArray.forEach(insertImages);

function insertImages(value) {
 this.setState({imageChosen: value})
}
```